# Class member type of a derived class

Tags: c++, class, templates, inheritance

Disclaimer: probably this question has been already asked but my lack of terminology knowledge is limiting my searches.

Let's say I have a base class

```
class A {
public:
  A (){};
  virtual ~A (){};
private:
  int valA = 0;
}
```

And a set of derived ones (`B,C,D,...`) like

```
class B: public A {
public:
  B (){};
  ~B (){};
  int more_functionalities(){return 7;}
private:
  int valB = 0;
}
```

At this point I have a main third class which has, as a member, a vector of derived class pointers, but which type is not known a priori. More specifically something like

```
class Top {
public:
  Top (const string derivedTypeName){m_derivedTypeName=derivedTypeName;};
  ~Top () {};
  //functionalities to create a vector of elements of the derived class 
  //(depending on m_derivedTypeName)
  vector<A/B *> getContent() {return m_content;}
private:
  string m_derivedTypeName;
  vector<A/B *> m_content;
}
```

Into the main functionality of `Top`, the object `m_content` will be populated as a vector of one of the derived classes `B,C,D,...` (depending on `m_derivedTypeName`).
The question is: how should I declare `m_content` if the type is not know a priori? Should I use the base class and then the user of `Top` will cast somehow (how?) the output of `getContent()`?

If there are multiple ways, what is the preferred method in general?

Comment: Why not make `Top` a template? Like `template<typename T> class Top { std::vector<T> m_content; };`?

Comment: a `vector<A*>` can store pointers to `B`. Though your desire for casts is due to poor design. The base class should define the interface you want to use on derived classes. If thats not the case and casts are needed then it isnt really polymorphism

Comment: And if the type is not known at compile-time, then consider polymorphism, pointers to the common base-class `A`, and virtual functions (instead of using `m_derivedTypeName`).

Comment: Are all objects in Top of the same type? Also, you propose ```vector<pointer>``` using raw pointers. Be careful about memory management and prefer smart pointers.

Comment: It depends. Are all elements of `m_content` of the same type? Should a `Top` that has `B` instances in its `m_content` be of same type as a `Top` that has `C` instances?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes I was thinking at some point of using a template but I was not sure it was the best idea. Also, the exact type will not be known at compile time, but only at run-time. 
@463035818_is_not_a_number the rest of `Top` will be identical, independently on the `B` or `C` cases. It's just the derived class constructor that is deeply different.

Comment: that sounds like a factory can help. Though there is too little context to decide what would be a good or "the best" way. "Top will be identical, independently on the B or C cases." that actually does not answer if they need to be of same type or not.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number actually is a need to have it of the same type but I was not specifying it to learn more about all the several possibilities. To specify more the context: I have some files that I have to decode and the several derived classes are describing the different decoding format. `Top` is what the user is supposed to call but again the type of derived class is potentially changing at run-time.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude when you say "And if the type is not known at compile-time, then consider polymorphism, pointers to the common base-class A, and virtual functions (instead of using m_derivedTypeName)" what do you practically mean? I am rereading it now more carefully and I am not sure exactly what you are proposing to get rid of `m_derivedTypeName `.

Comment: Your ```getContent``` method returns a copy of the entire vector. Is that really necessary? A const reference would be significantly more efficient. This also has large implications if we think about using smart pointers.